# ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 7: Invalid default value for 'LAST_UPDATED'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Running MySQL 5.5, got the error above when I tried to import a .sql file

I've checked the SQL_MODE of my server and nothing similar to 'NO_ZERO_DATE' is found

As well, I've took out the text of 'STRICT_MODE' from my my.ini file and restarted the server, yet this error still persists

Here's the .sql file being imported

```
CREATE TABLE  `street_segment` (
  `ID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `PROVINCE_CODE` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `POSTAL_CODE` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `MUNICIPALITY_NAME` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `DIRECTORY_AREA_NAME` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `STREET_NAME` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `STREET_TYPE_CODE` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `STREET_DIRECTION_CODE` varchar(2) default NULL,
  `ADDRESS_SEQ_CODE` int(8) default NULL,
  `STREET_ADDRESS_FROM_NUMBER` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `STREET_ADDRESS_TO_NUMBER` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `NUMBER_SUFFIX_FROM` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `NUMBER_SUFFIX_TO` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `SUITE_NUMBER_FROM` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `SUITE_NUMBER_TO` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `STREET_NAME_ACCENT_F` int(1) default 0,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 12):

This error can occur when you attempt to import a file into MySQL Server 5.6.4 and earlier, when the database was created on and exported from MySQL 5.6.5 or later.

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for `TIMESTAMP`, and for at most one `TIMESTAMP` column per table."
>
> — https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

It has been suggested that the workaround was to use `TIMESTAMP` rather than `DATETIME` for this column, since that appears to work, but that solution may fail for multiple reasons.  Additionally, though it gives the initial appearance of working for this specific table, MySQL Server versions before 5.6.5 have other limitations and implicit behavior for `TIMESTAMP` columns such that this workaround would not be usable in every case.

Notably, in all reasonably modern (5.x and up) versions of MySQL Server the `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` data types are not fully interchangeable.  `DATETIME` columns support a broader range of values than `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP` is subject to the database connection's notion of time zones, with automatic time zone conversions, while `DATETIME` is not.

Since the database was created on 5.6 or later, for optimum compatibility, you should be loading it onto a server that is also 5.6 or later.  Throughout the 5.x series, things are generally backward-compatible; that is, it is generally possible to restore a dump file on a later version of the server, but due to the introduction of new features, the reverse is not as true.

See also:

- [Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html)
- [The `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)
- [Should I use `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409286/1695906)

Answer (score 2):

**mysql error 1067 invalid default value for timestamp**

1. Start Cmd.
2. Type mysql -u root -p Then Press Enter.
3. And Select Your Database (Ex "USE DATABASE ").
4. Type this

   **SET @@session.sql_mode ="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";**
5. And Then Press Enter.

For more information : https://buddhikal.blogspot.com/2017/01/mysql-error-1067-invalid-default-value.html

Answer (score 1):

Solved the error by changing `DATETIME` to `TIMESTAMP`. As indicated [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html), "Use of `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is specific to `TIMESTAMP`".

Comment: You may want to [request merging of your accounts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SET sql_mode = "";` in the beginning of your SQL CODE. The [MySql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) provides some detail.